# Deleting HKWorkout on iPhone doesn't delete it on apple watch

Tags: watchkit, watchos-2, healthkit

This is what I'm doing:

- save a HKWorkout object on the apple watch with samples (works fine)
- select the workout on the apple watch (works fine)
- after a while in can select the workout on the associated iPhone (works fine)
- (opening apples activity app seems to make "after a while" faster)
- I now can delete the workout with the iPhone app (works fine)

The problem: the deletion of the workout on the iPhone seems not to be propagated back to the watch. So the deleted workout still is selectable on the watch.

I would expect that a deletion is propagated back to the watch automatically.

Is there a way to propagate the deletion from the iPhone to the watch?

Or do I habe to delete the workout twice, on the iPhone and on the watch?

Tested on iOS 9.1, watchOS 2.0.1, real hardware, not the simulator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to delete the workout on both devices because HealthKit does not propagate the deletion in either direction.

Note that the workout sample will expire on the watch automatically after about 7 days so it's not strictly necessary to delete it explicitly unless you'd like to show an accurate workout history for the past week on the watch.

Comment: Thanks Allan. I am aware that the workout history is deleted after about 7 days on the watch. In this case the workout history is an essential part of the user interface, so it would be confusing to show it on the watch when the user has deleted it on the iPhone. Now I know I have to implement the propagation myself.